# How do I report a ratio?

Tags: data

I want to report a ratio in my thesis. The ratio is 16:84, but I also want tot report which number represents which class. Can I report that like this:

> The data was not evenly distributed with a ratio of 16:84 (CN:AD).

Or should I put the CN:AD in square brackets? And is it clear if I report it like this?

UPDATE:
Now reported it as:

> The data were unevenly distributed with a ratio CN:AD = 16:84.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Is this a ratio, or an N? That is, does 16 represent 16 data points or 16*X?

Comment: Looks fine (as long as the gentle reader knows what CN, AD is all about).

Comment: The way you have written it implies that the ratio was not 16:84. You need a comma, or better yet use the word “unevenly”.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson thank you! Will apply your suggestion

Comment: @BryanKrause it's a ratio. N would be 52,507 data points versus 9,828 data points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by [xLeitix](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/144813/20058), there aren't really any standards on this. Another possibly clearer way to report that ratio is:

> The data were not evenly distributed with a ratio CN:AD = 16:84.

Comment: I think this is about as standard as it gets...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there are really any standards for this kind of thing, but what's wrong with writing?

> CN and AD were not evenly distributed (ratio 16 to 84).

Your version would work for me as well, but my proposal feels maybe a tiny bit clearer.